# Beginner Java Payroll Program, While loop with nested if else if controls, need to count how many "yes" answers

Tags: java, string, if-statement, counter

Working on a beginner payroll program with a while loop controlled by the number of employees.

In the while loop the employees are sorted by salary.

"if" salary < 85K the employee paid hourly and is eligible for overtime.

"else" (salary > 85) the employee is "salaried employee" and is not eligible for overtime.

Within both the "if" and "else" branches of code there are nested if/else/if else controls for tax brackets, overtime, paid time off etc.

Within both the "if" and "else" branches I ask if the employee has company health insurance so I can deduct the cost of the insurance from the employees pay.

This my code for asking does the employee have company health insurance, YES/NO?

---

```
System.out.println("Does " + empName + " have company health insurance?  Enter YES or NO.");

        yesORno = input.next();

                    if (yesORno.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {

                        System.out.println(empName + " Has company health insurance and pays $300 each pay period.");

                        empAfterInsuranceAnnual = empAnnualNet - 7800;
                        empAfterInsurancePP = empPayPeriodNet - 300;


                        System.out.println(empName + " Net annual income after taxes and health insurance is $" + empAfterInsuranceAnnual +".");
                        System.out.println(empName + " Net pay period income after taxes and health insurance is $" + empAfterInsurancePP + ".");   
                    }


                    else if (yesORno.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")) {

                        System.out.println(empName + " does not have company health insurance payroll deduction");
                    }
```

---

The program compiles and now I want to add some additional outputs and I need number of "Yes" answers.

How do I add a counter to keep track of the number of YES answers.?

I need the total number of YES answers when the loop is finished so I can calculate the total health insurance cost.

Thank you, for your insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a counter variable like this:

```
int yes;

if (yesORno.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
    yes++;

    // the rest of your TRUE code here
}
else {
    // the rest of your FALSE code here
}
```

Make sure to increment yes (`yes++`) everywhere your code branches to handle a "yes" answer from the user.

NOTE: You don't need to use an `else if` when your conditional only has two outcomes. A simple `else` will suffice. Save your `else if` for cases where the user can answer "yes", "no" or "maybe".

Comment: or utilize it like `if (yes) { ... } else if (no) { ... } else { other input, ask for input again }` for needing to handle incorrect input if neither "yes" nor "no" were entered ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  So simple and was just what I needed.  First programming class of any kind and I tend to overthink and miss the obvious.  I also got rid of all the else if's that were not needed.  Thanks, again.

Comment: @Mike Happy to help. Please look to the left side of the answer and click the checkmark to accept the answer so that other people viewing your question in the future know what helped.